# How to write a UNIX command line to sort the lines of poetry based on the second words in each line

Tags: linux

Write a UNIX command line to sort the lines of poetry based on the second words in each line

I know sort based on field is

```css
sort –k 2 poetry
```

but how do i sort by word?

Comment: I guess you need to read the manual page to answer your homework. Anyway the order of li nes makes poetry good. Why destroy an art form through sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *does* sort by word. "Fields" are separated by spaces, and so sorting by the second field is the same thing as sorting by the second word.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat poetry.txt | awk '{print $2, $0}' | sort | awk '{$1="";sub("  "," ")}1'
```

THis basically rewrites the poetry and prefixes each line with the second field.  Then it does a sort.  Then it removes the extra second field (which is in field 1).

Comment: Thx think it beyonds whats asking. but i will take notes for your comment